# jquery: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, replace, undefined

```
if ($("body").hasClass("tax-series")) {
        imgArray = {
                        "term-open-art": "/clone/files/2016/05/series-treasures-vault.gif",
                        "term-gettyinspired": "/clone/files/2016/05/series-getty-inspired.gif",
                        "term-medieval-manuscripts-alive": "/clone/files/2016/05/series-mm-alive.gif"
                    };
        $.each( imgArray, function( key, value ) {
            if ( $("body").hasClass(key) ) {
                $("#content-area h1").replaceWith( "<img src='" + value + "' class='series-image'>" );
            } else {
                var str = $("#content-area h1").html().replace("Series:", '');
                $("#content-area h1").html(str);    
            }
        }); 

    }
```

The line that's throwing the error is :

```
var str = $("#content-area h1").html().replace("Series:", '');
```

The weird thing is, it's doing what it's supposed to do, but because of the error, the functions that come after aren't running. I could just move this block of code to the bottom, but I'd rather not be throwing errors around. And yes, I did a search, but nothing seemed relevant to this one.

Comment: You usually get that error when you try to work on a undefined value, try outputting the `$("#content-area h1").html()` before you start replacing its contents; maybe it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: You will get that error if `$("#content-area h1")` does not find any element. If you put `console.log($("#content-area h1").length);` right before the `$("#content-area h1")` it most likely will show `0`.

Comment: @gttygrl It's hard to debug without an [mcve].  Perhaps you could show the HTML too.

Comment: ETA: Nope, nevermind, that didn't do it.
======
Aha! Thank you, I split that line into two, and now it works. (

`var str = $("#content-area h1").html();
str = str.replace("Series:", '');`

Comment: Must've been cached, 'cause the error's gone now. Thanks for the help!